# Crypto++ Init-Update-Final get cipher output

Tags: crypto++

In a effort to encrypt large file using Crypto++, I am following ecrypting using Java-like Init-Update-Final [in Crypto++](https://www.cryptopp.com/wiki/Init-Update-Final),

The demo code seem to work, everytime the Put is invoked, the output byte is printed to screen:

```
encoder.Put(buffer, ready);
```

But I can't find anyway to get the output of all cipher text. For example

```
'H' -> print 01 to screen 
'E' -> print A9 to screen 
'L' -> print 5J to screen 
'L' -> print 13 to screen 
'O' -> print 3d to screen ...
```

But I can't retrieve the full result to a byte array
01A95J133d...

A question [in here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37777373/encrypt-file-using-file-buffer-loop) related to using Init-Update-Final to encrypt large files but seem like not provided a working solution yet.

This is the full demo code:

```
enum { ENCRYPT_MODE = 1, DECRYPT_MODE = 2 };
struct JavaAlgorithmParameter
{
    JavaAlgorithmParameter()
        : key(NULL), ksize(0), iv(NULL), vsize(0) {}

    const byte* key;
    size_t ksize;
    const byte* iv;
    size_t vsize;
};

/////////////////////////
/////////////////////////

class JavaCipher
{
public:
    static JavaCipher* getInstance(const std::string& transformation);

    void init(int opmode, const JavaAlgorithmParameter& params);
    size_t update(const byte* in, size_t isize, byte* out, size_t osize);
    size_t final(byte* out, size_t osize);

    std::string getAlgorithm() const;

protected:
    JavaCipher(const std::string& transformation);

private:
    std::string m_transformation;
    member_ptr<SymmetricCipher> m_cipher;
    member_ptr<StreamTransformationFilter> m_filter;
};

/////////////////////////
/////////////////////////

JavaCipher* JavaCipher::getInstance(const std::string& transformation)
{
    return new JavaCipher(transformation);
}

JavaCipher::JavaCipher(const std::string& transformation)
    : m_transformation(transformation) { }

std::string JavaCipher::getAlgorithm() const
{
    return m_transformation;
}

/////////////////////////
/////////////////////////

size_t JavaCipher::final(byte* out, size_t osize)
{
    m_filter.get()->MessageEnd();

    if (!out || !osize || !m_filter.get()->AnyRetrievable())
        return 0;

    size_t t = CryptoPP::STDMIN(m_filter.get()->MaxRetrievable(), (word64)osize);
    t = m_filter.get()->Get(out, t);
    return t;
}

/////////////////////////
/////////////////////////

size_t JavaCipher::update(const byte* in, size_t isize, byte* out, size_t osize)
{
    if (in && isize)
        m_filter.get()->Put(in, isize);

    if (!out || !osize || !m_filter.get()->AnyRetrievable())
        return 0;

    size_t t = STDMIN(m_filter.get()->MaxRetrievable(), (word64)osize);
    t = m_filter.get()->Get(out, t);
    return t;
}

/////////////////////////
/////////////////////////

void JavaCipher::init(int opmode, const JavaAlgorithmParameter& params)
{
    if (m_transformation == "AES/ECB/PKCSPadding" && opmode == ENCRYPT_MODE)
    {
        m_cipher.reset(new ECB_Mode<AES>::Encryption);
        m_cipher.get()->SetKey(params.key, params.ksize);
        m_filter.reset(new StreamTransformationFilter(*m_cipher.get(), NULL, BlockPaddingSchemeDef::PKCS_PADDING));
    }
    else if (m_transformation == "AES/ECB/PKCSPadding" && opmode == DECRYPT_MODE)
    {
        m_cipher.reset(new ECB_Mode<AES>::Decryption);
        m_cipher.get()->SetKey(params.key, params.ksize);
        m_filter.reset(new StreamTransformationFilter(*m_cipher.get(), NULL, BlockPaddingSchemeDef::PKCS_PADDING));
    }
    else if (m_transformation == "AES/CBC/PKCSPadding" && opmode == ENCRYPT_MODE)
    {
        m_cipher.reset(new CBC_Mode<AES>::Encryption);
        m_cipher.get()->SetKeyWithIV(params.key, params.ksize, params.iv);
        m_filter.reset(new StreamTransformationFilter(*m_cipher.get(), NULL, BlockPaddingSchemeDef::PKCS_PADDING));
    }
    else if (m_transformation == "AES/CBC/PKCSPadding" && opmode == DECRYPT_MODE)
    {
        m_cipher.reset(new CBC_Mode<AES>::Decryption);
        m_cipher.get()->SetKeyWithIV(params.key, params.ksize, params.iv);
        m_filter.reset(new StreamTransformationFilter(*m_cipher.get(), NULL, BlockPaddingSchemeDef::PKCS_PADDING));
    }
    else if (m_transformation == "AES/CTR/NoPadding" && opmode == ENCRYPT_MODE)
    {
        m_cipher.reset(new CTR_Mode<AES>::Encryption);
        m_cipher.get()->SetKeyWithIV(params.key, params.ksize, params.iv);
        m_filter.reset(new StreamTransformationFilter(*m_cipher.get(), NULL, BlockPaddingSchemeDef::NO_PADDING));
    }
    else if (m_transformation == "AES/CTR/NoPadding" && opmode == DECRYPT_MODE)
    {
        m_cipher.reset(new CTR_Mode<AES>::Decryption);
        m_cipher.get()->SetKeyWithIV(params.key, params.ksize, params.iv);
        m_filter.reset(new StreamTransformationFilter(*m_cipher.get(), NULL, BlockPaddingSchemeDef::NO_PADDING));
    }
    else
        throw NotImplemented(m_transformation + " is not implemented");
}

/////////////////////////
/////////////////////////

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    try
    {
        byte key[32], iv[16];
        OS_GenerateRandomBlock(false, key, COUNTOF(key));
        OS_GenerateRandomBlock(false, iv, COUNTOF(iv));

        HexEncoder encoder(new FileSink(cout));

        JavaAlgorithmParameter params;
        params.key = key;
        params.ksize = COUNTOF(key);
        params.iv = iv;
        params.vsize = COUNTOF(iv);

        //JavaCipher* cipher = JavaCipher::getInstance("AES/CTR/NoPadding");
        JavaCipher* cipher = JavaCipher::getInstance("AES/CBC/PKCSPadding");
        cipher->init(ENCRYPT_MODE, params);

        cout << "Algorithm: " << cipher->getAlgorithm() << endl;

        cout << "Key: ";
        encoder.Put(key, COUNTOF(key));
        cout << endl;

        cout << "IV: ";
        encoder.Put(iv, COUNTOF(iv));
        cout << endl;

        char * allText = FileUtil::readAllByte("1MB.txt");
        long len = strlen(allText);

        byte buffer[64];

        size_t ready = 0;

        for (unsigned int i = 0; i <= len; i++)
        {
            byte b = allText[i];

            //cout << "Put 0x";
            encoder.Put(b);
            cout << endl;

            ready = cipher->update(&b, 1, buffer, COUNTOF(buffer));

            if (ready)
            {
                //cout << "Get: ";
                encoder.Put(buffer, ready);
                cout << endl;
            }
        }

        ready = cipher->final(NULL, 0);
        if (ready)
        {
            //cout << "Final: ";
            encoder.Put(buffer, ready);
            cout << endl;
        }

        ready = cipher->final(buffer, COUNTOF(buffer));
        if (ready)
        {
            //cout << "Final: ";
            encoder.Put(buffer, ready);
            cout << endl;
        }

        delete cipher;
        getchar();
    }
    catch (const Exception& ex)
    {
        cerr << ex.what() << endl;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: You seem to be a C# developer. Is it not possible to accomplish your task using C# instead of C++? .Net seems to have everything you need.

Comment: Sorry :) I made all them in C# in oneday. But I think it wil be better and faster on a multithread C++ library like Crypto++.

Comment: My apologies that the help I have been trying to provide has not been helpful. Perhaps you should learn more about C++ before you continue with the Crypto++ library.

Comment: Yes, I will and have to learn more about C++. Thank you very much for your help and let me apologize for my lacking knowledge :)

Comment: @jww: Just a small question, is there a way to avoid the code to print out put continually like 
Put 0x52
Put 0x58
Put 0x55
Put 0x32
Put 0x32
Put 0x4B
Put 0x57
Put 0x59
Put 0x30
Put 0x43
Put 0x4F
Put 0x34
Put 0x43
Put 0x56
Put 0x00
?

Comment: The `HexEncoder` is tied to `cout`. Remove the statement `HexEncoder encoder(new FileSink(cout))`, and then fix the compile errors related to the variable `encoder`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> But I can't find anyway to get the output of all cipher text. For
>   example
>
> ```
> 'H' -> print 01 to screen 
> 'E' -> print A9 to screen 
> 'L' -> print 5J to screen 
> 'L' -> print 13 to screen 
> 'O' -> print 3d to screen ...
> ```
>
> But I can't retrieve the full result to a byte array 01A95J133d...

Call `cipher::update` with no output buffer:

```
cipher->update(&b, 1, NULL, 0);
```

Then, retrieve the buffer after you call `cipher::final`:

```
size_t size = <some appropriately size for the cipher text>;
byte result[size];
cipher->final(result, size);
```

If you are having trouble with `<some appropriately size for the cipher text>`, then add a new method to the class:

```
size_t ready() const
{
    return m_filter.get()->MaxRetrievable();
}
```